# What differences are between `format()` and `str()`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

```
>>> format(sys.stdout)
"<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>"
>>> str(sys.stdout)
"<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>"
```

I am not very sure about the following quotes from Python library references. What differences are between `format()` and `str()`, or between `object.__format__(self, format_spec)` and `object.__str__(self )`? When shall we use which?

> `object.__str__(self )`
>
> Called by str(object) and the built-in functions format() and print()
>   to compute the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of
>   an object.
>
> `object.__format__(self, format_spec)`
>
> Called by the format() built-in function, and by extension, evaluation
>   of formatted string literals and the str.format() method, to produce a
>   “formatted” string representation of an object.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity. Do you know the purpose of `repr(sys.stdout)`? It is also a string representation of a class. If you don't know that I may put it in the answer as well...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am gonna break down the main three (technically main 2 because `__format__` is not commonly implemented). I'll go through all three then put it all together in one nice class.

---

The most common `__str__`:

This is how you want to represent this object as a `str`.
Often this is less detailed than `__repr__` and is used
mainly for the end user. For example if we have a `person` class we may implement `str` this way:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Hello my name is {self.name}" 

p = Person("John Smith")
print(str(p)) # Prints "Hello my name is John Smith"
```

---

The less common `__repr__`:

To be honest I implement this more than `str` for most projects. This should return the representation of the object as a `str` in such a way that it is helpful to the *developer* instead of the end user and is called via `repr(my_obj)`.  If a class does not implement a `__str__` magic method then python will attempt to call its `__repr__` method automatically when you use `str(my_obj)` (thus you can implement `repr` first and `str` later). Often the `repr` of a class returns the way to recreate that object. For example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Person(name='{self.name}')"

p = Person("John Smith")
print(repr(p)) # Prints "Person(name='John Smith')"
print(str(p))  # Prints "Person(name='John Smith')"
```

---

The cursed child `__format__`: [I just call it that because it is so uncommonly used :)]

The main difference between `__format__` and the other two methods is that it also accepts a `format_spec` that can be used to style the returned string.

To understand this in further detail I must first explain some formatting stuff. You may have seen some of this stuff before or you may not have.

Lets use a dummy class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Person(name="{self.name}", age={self.age})'
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

p = Person(name="John Smith", age=22)
# This prints the str of p
print("{!s}".format(p)) # John Smith
# This prints the representation of p
print("{!r}".format(p)) # Person(name="John Smith", age=22)
```

Okay so you can format your class as its `str` or as its `repr`, but what if you want to format it your own way? Most people don't need to do this; but, this is the power of python, you can do **anything**. We can create different tags instead of `r` and `s` (though it uses `:` instead of `!`):

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Person(name="{self.name}", age={self.age})'
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        if format_spec == 'age': # get a persons age
            return f"{self.name} is {self.age} years old"
        elif format_spec == 'birthday':
            return "Yesterday"
        return str(self) # A default case

p = Person(name="John Smith", age=22)
# This prints the str of p
print("{!s}".format(p))
# This with representation of p
print("{!r}".format(p))
print("{:age}".format(p))
print("{:birthday}".format(p))
print(f"{p:age} and his birthday was {p:birthday}")
```

There is obviously more to this than my limited knowledge can go into but this should be a good general scope :).

There are some packages that use this such as `datetime`. If you are interested learning more about the power of format **Pyformat** walks through this pretty well: [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/).

### Disclaimer:

I do not have much experience using `__format__` so I can not provide a good use-case (though datetime's use-case isn't bad).  Everything here is just to show the broad difference between `str`, `repr`, and `format` magic methods.  If I got anything wrong (especially `__format__`'s use-case) please let me know and I will update it.