# Formatted Python string uses neither repr nor str - what is happening?

Tags: python, string, enums, string-formatting, repr

I have an enumeration `ResourceType` that inherits from both `namedtuple` and `Enum`, and I don't override `__str__` or `__repr__` anywhere. When I format an instance of that enum I unexpectedly get just the undecorated value, as opposed to either the `repr()` or the `str()`. How is this possible? What is being called?

**Enum details (simplified):**

```
from enum import Enum, auto
from collections import namedtuple

class ResourceType(namedtuple('ResourceType', 'value ext required'), Enum):
    RGB = auto(), '.png', True
```

**Output:**

```
>>> repr(ResourceType.RGB)
"<ResourceType.RGB: ResourceType(value=<enum.auto object at 0x7f44b7d48d30>, ext='.png', required=True)>"

>>> str(ResourceType.RGB)
'ResourceType.RGB'

>>> f"{ResourceType.RGB}"
"ResourceType(value=<enum.auto object at 0x7f44b7d48d30>, ext='.png', required=True)"
```

The last value is neither the `repr()` nor the `str()`, so even if `namedtuple` is providing that string, why does it not also provide the str/repr?

Comment: can you test what the output of the [`__format__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) method is? For example `ResourceType.RGB.__format__("s")`

Comment: @Felk: With `__format__("")` I get the same as the `f-string` output.

Comment: In either Python 3.11 or 3.12 enum's `__format__` will return the same thing as enum's `__str__`. You're current workaround will still work, but will no longer be necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you insert an object into an f-string in this way it calls the [`__format__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#controlling-formatting-on-a-per-type-basis) method.

```
from enum import Enum, auto
from collections import namedtuple

class ResourceType(namedtuple('ResourceType', 'value ext required'), Enum):
    RGB = auto(), '.png', True

    def __repr__(self):
        return "REPR"

    def __str__(self):
        return "STR"

    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        return "FORMAT"

print(repr(ResourceType.RGB))
print(str(ResourceType.RGB))
print(f"{ResourceType.RGB}")
```

gives output of

```
REPR
STR
FORMAT
```

Comment: I found this helpful for understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56403814/12235376

Answer (score 3):

Now that Kemp and Daweo have pointed out that the magic is happening via `__format__`, I was able to dig a little deeper, and indeed inside the `Enum` class we find:

```
def __format__(self, format_spec):
    # mixed-in Enums should use the mixed-in type's __format__, otherwise
    # we can get strange results with the Enum name showing up instead of
    # the value

    # pure Enum branch
    if self._member_type_ is object:
        cls = str
        val = str(self)
    # mix-in branch
    else:
        cls = self._member_type_
        val = self._value_
    return cls.__format__(val, format_spec)
```

`ResourceType` is a mixed-in enum due to the inheritance of `namedtuple` as well, and so for the `__format__` case, the call is redirected to the 'ResourceType' `namedtuple` with just the value of the enum instance, which is stored in `_value_` by convention/implementation.

In my case I wanted the `ResourceType` enum to appear externally like an enum as much as possible, despite also being a namedtuple, so I have now changed it to:

```
class ResourceType(namedtuple('ResourceType', 'value ext required'), Enum):
    RGB = auto(), '.png', True
    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        return str.__format__(str(self), format_spec)
```

This is exactly equivalent to just forcing the 'pure Enum branch' in the `Enum.__format__` implementation.

Comment: In either Python 3.11 or 3.12 enum's `__format__` will return the same thing as enum's `__str__`.  You're current workaround will still work, but will no longer be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

*What is being called?*

It is `Enum.__format__` whose doc-string in [enum.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/enum.py) states that it

> Returns format using actual value type unless `__str__` has been
> overridden.

Comment: The `namedtuple`'s `__format__` is the one getting called.

Comment: @Kemp `Enum.__format__` is being called, and this redirects to the `namedtuple`'s `__format__` because it detects it's a mixed-in type

Comment: Which means that `namedtuple.__format__` is the one that is called. The doc string for `enum.__format__` isn't very useful in that situation because it's telling us what would be returned for the non-mixed-in case.